# Is there a way to switch branches with already committed changes on the main branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a simple to-do application that's being hosted on Netlify, so when I push the changes to the main branch it will automatically build and deploy them to the domain, I've been migrating to typescript and changing some styles for a while and committing changes without thinking that I should do that on a different branch, so now I have tons of commits on the main branch which I haven't pushed yet because it's not ready to be deployed, but I do want to have it on a different branch on github, so what would be the best way to switch to a new branch if I already have committed lots of changes on the main one?

Comment: Why not just checkout a new branch? Or do you want to checkout from a specific commit on master? If that is the case, then go to master branch `git checkout master` --> `git checkout <commit-HASH-from-where-you-want-to-branch-out>` --> `git switch -c <branch-name>` . You can confirm the result with a `git log --oneline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a branch from the `HEAD` of main. (`git checkout -b feature/migration` - call it whatever you like, don't need to be *feature/migration*)
2. Go back to `main`. (`git checkout main`)
3. Reset the `HEAD` to the remote. (`git reset --hard origin/main`)
4. Confirm on Git log to make sure `HEAD` is on the same commit as the `main` and `origin/main`

Obviously push the new branch (`feature/migration`) to Github to be on the safe side